# Monitor weblogic by zabbix

Tags: weblogic, zabbix

I want monitor weblogic server by zabbix.
I do import template weblogic in zabbix but I don't know how to work.
please help me for monitor weblogic server.

Comment: What did you try? What do you want to monitor? What problems did you hit? I guess jmx plays a role here ….